# What is the best way to use nested promises and await

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I want to fetch all posts of the current user and all posts of his friends. The code is working but I'm confused about using async-await and Promise.all together. How should I handle errors when I use them together and what's the best way to use nested async functions? Thanks in advance.

```js
router.get("/timeline", verify, async(req, res, next) => {
  let postArray = [];
  try {
    const posts = await Post.find({
      userId: req.user.id
    });
    postArray.push(...posts);
    const currentUser = await User.findById(req.user.id);
    const promises = currentUser.friends.map(async(friendId) => {
      const posts = await Post.find({
        userId: friendId
      });
      posts.map((p) => postArray.push(p));
    });
    await Promise.all(promises).then(() => res.send(postArray));
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

**verify** middleware is by JWT validator. And my models are like these:

```js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      min: 3,
      max: 20,
      unique: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      max: 50,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      min: 6,
      max: 1024,
    },
    profilePicture: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    coverPicture: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    friends: {
      type: Array,
      default: [],
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

```js
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    userId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    desc: {
      type: String,
      max: 500
    },
    img: {
      type: String,
    },
    likes: {
      type: Array,
      default: [],
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my simplified version:

```
router.get("/timeline", verify, async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const postArray = await Post.find({ userId: req.user.id });
        const currentUser = await User.findById(req.user.id);
        await Promise.all(currentUser.friends.map(friendId => {
            return Post.find({ userId: friendId }).then(fPosts => postArray.push(...fPosts));
        }));
        res.send(postArray);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
```

Changes:

1. Just initialize `postArray` with the first bit of data, rather than declaring it as an empty array and then pushing into it from another array.
2. Rather than iterate `posts` each time, just push them all into `postArray` with one operation
3. I'm not a fan of using an `async` callback with `await` in a `.map()` because it implies to the casual reader that the `.map()` loop will actually pause for the `await` (which it will not).  So, instead I just use `.then()` to collect the friend posts into `postArray` and return the promise from `Post.find()`.

> I'm confused about using async-await and Promise.all together

You use `Promise.all()` anytime you have more than one promise and you want to know when they are all done.  This can be used with `async/await` just fine because they also operation on promises.  In my example, I do `return Post.find()` inside the `.map()` loop which means the return from `.map()` will be an array of promises which is perfect to use with `Promise.all()` to know when they are all done.

> How should I handle errors when I use them together

If you `await Promise.all()`, then error handling for that works just like all your other `await` statements.  Errors will be caught by your surrounding `try/catch`.

> what's the best way to use nested async functions

There's really no single answer to this.  You had one approach that worked.  I offered a slight variation on it that seemed simpler to me.  Simplicity is in the eye of the beholder.

---

FYI, some people don't like seeing `.then()` and `await` in the same block of code - expecting you to go with one idiom or the other.  I don't ascribe to those type of black and white rules, but prefer to use whatever seems simpler to me which occasionally sees me mix them for a particular situation.

Here's a modified version of the code above without the `.then()` if you so prefer:

```
router.get("/timeline", verify, async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const postArray = await Post.find({ userId: req.user.id });
        const currentUser = await User.findById(req.user.id);
        await Promise.all(currentUser.friends.map(async friendId => {
            let fPosts = await Post.find({ userId: friendId });
            postArray.push(...fPosts);
        }));
        res.send(postArray);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**jfriend00**'s answer is great. Just adding to it, if you wanted to show a custom error if your api fails to load friend's post, you can do so by doing something like this.

```
router.get("/timeline", verify, async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const postArray = await Post.find({ userId: req.user.id });
        const currentUser = await User.findById(req.user.id);
        await Promise.all(currentUser.friends.map(async friendId => {
            let fPosts = await Post.find({ userId: friendId });
            postArray.push(...fPosts);
        })).catch((e) => {
             throw new Error("Failed to load friend's post")    // notice a separate catch 
        })
        res.send(postArray);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
```